# Reset Data Validation Lists to first item, method range has failed

Tags: excel, vba

so another user suggested a way to reset a range of cells to their respective data validation lists firsts item ( as highlighted in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xTXv.png)  he and [this other user](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/macro-to-select-first-top-option-in-data/0ecac909-a91e-4624-8eb0-ea9c4d95f832) suggested the same solution, but i keep getting the runtime error "method 'Range' has failed" on the following line:
**Cell.Value = Range(Split(Mid(Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2), ":")(0)).Value**

[my actual worksheet](http://uploaded.net/file/tvjdlhzu) if needed.

I am stuck, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your formula takes `Cell.Validation.Formula1` (which you can Debug.Print to the Immediate Window to look at). Of this it drops the first character: `Mid(Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2)`. What remains after that (look at it in the Immediate Window) is split on ":" and the first element (Index 0) is returned as a range name that is then used to specify which range's value to return. This can also be printed. After you have examine the formula's output in this way you will know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know  ( Cell.Validation.Formula1 is the source of my data validation list  "=Talents!$H$4:$H$9"

Answer (score 0):

Here are three solutions to your problem. They differ by how the list in the data validation is defined.

```
Private Sub Test()

    Dim Cell As Range

    ' Cell contains a comma separated list
    Set Cell = Cells(2, 2)
    Cell.Value = Split(Cell.Validation.Formula1, ",")(0)

    ' Cell contains a reference to a named range
    ' but should also work for a worksheet reference
    Set Cell = Cells(4, 2)
    Cell.Value = Range(Mid(Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2)).Cells(1).Value

    ' cell contains a reference to a range
    Set Cell = Cells(6, 2)
    Cell.Value = Range(Split(Mid(Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2), ":")(0)).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , the split function seems to be the problem. The mid function returns Talents!$H$4:$H$9 but  Split("Talents!$H$4:$H$9", ":")(0)   doesntt return anything... even though Talents!$H$4 contains the value "0/5" which would be correct.

Comment: ok what finally worked for me  is  Cell.Value = Split(Cell.Validation.Formula1, ":")(0)   thanks for the help

Comment: If `Split(Cell.Validation.Formula1, ":")` worked then there should be no equal sign in the validation list definition (`Formula1`) which should render the drop-down inoperable. From here it looks like you are almost there, almost leaving the "try this" phase and take command of the formula by understanding how it works. Give it one more round. :-)